# Node.js - Push Recursively into an Array Using Async FS

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, filesystems

I am trying to use the `fs` `readdir` to create a function that push file names into an array, recursively (including files in sub directories), using default attribute `dir` as a starting point.

When I tried to `console.log` the names it worked fine, but I could not figure out how to create an array with all the names in it (I'm not getting the files in the sub directories).

```
  import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';

   const arr = [];
   const reader = async (dir = `./src`) => {
      try {
         const items = await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
         items.map(item => item.isDirectory() ? reader(`${dir}/${item.name}`) : arr.push(item.name));
      }
      catch (err) {
         console.log(err);
      }
   };

   reader().then(() => {
      console.log(arr)
   })
```

Thanks!

Comment: Promise.all might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362559/13583510

Answer (score 0):

You're not `await`ing the call to `reader()`, and you're also not calling `.then()` on it.

so execution just continues, `console.log(arr)` executes with an empty array, and then subsequent calls to `reader()` actually take place and push to the array.

Fixed version:

```
const arr = [];
const reader = async (dir = `./src`) => {
    try {
        const items = await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
        for (const item of items) {
            (item.isDirectory()) {
                await reader(`${dir}/${item.name}`);
            } else {
                arr.push(item.name);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

reader().then(() => {
    console.log(arr)
})
```

Comment: don't `catch` inside the function. let the error bubble up so the consumer can choose what to do with it. if `console.log` is what they want, that is for them to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You're close but one hint there's a mistake is the use of `.map` without using its result. `.map` is constructing an array of promises, each of which need some sort of processing to assemble the final output.

I would recommend using a generator instead of forcing the results into an array. This side-steps the need for `.map` and allows the consumer to process the resulting files asynchronously as they arrive -

```js
import { readdir } from "fs/promises"
import { join } from "path"

async function* ls(path = ".") {
  for (const dirent of await readdir(path, { withFileTypes: true }))
    if (dirent.isDirectory())
      yield *ls(join(path, dirent.name))
    else
      yield join(path, dirent.name)
}
```

```js
for await (const f of ls("/foo"))
  console.log("file found:", f)
```

```
file1
file2
file3
...
```

If indeed the consumer wishes to convert the asynchronous stream of elements to a flat array, a generic `toArray` can be used -

```js
async function toArray(iter) {
  const r = []
  for await (const v of iter)
    r.push(v)
  return r
}
```

```js
console.log("all files", await toArray(ls("/foo)))
```

```js
[ file1, file2, file3, ... ]
```